# What is the chrome object?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I just stumbled on a global object in chrome called chrome, I have no idea what this object is and I haven't been able to find any information on it (this is not the same as the chrome object for apps/extensions).  Is this like some sort of object that chrome uses to test out new features?

Comment: With some playing around I also found `chrome.webstore.install(url, onSuccess, onFailure)`. Interesting! +1

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too, I can sort of guess at what some of the properties/methods do, but some of them aren't that clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the name of the object, I would guess that the purpose of if is as a utility for Chrome extension developers, even though it exposes methods that might be useful on regular websites not within the bounds of an extension.

Some APIs seem to have a very narrow purpose, [`chrome.webstore.install()`](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation) used for extension installation for instance. Others methods and properties, like [`chrome.csi().pageT`](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation) to get the time since the page was loaded, could possibly be useful outside the context of an extension, but since no other browser is likely to expose them, I don't see any good use of the APIs outside there intended context.

Unfortunately, the Chrome Developer website is a bit cranky today, throwing HTTP 500, but at least according to the Google search results, you should be able to find information about the `chrome.webstore` and `chrome.appNotifications` APIs as soon as the developer site is alive and kicking again. `chrome.appNotifications` appears to be related to desktop notifications though.

The object seem to be a bit of a hidden treasure and I haven't been able to find a decent list, describing all the exposed APIs. So for now, the easiest way to get information about the various APIs is probably to inspect the `chrome` object in Dev Tools and then google for the methods that catch your eye.

Comment: The documented chrome.* APIs are listed here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/